# how to change color based on the condition set for the textbox output in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web

what I'm trying to do is to change the color of the text to red when the label's text meet the condition.The font really did change color but if the next output don't meet the requirement,the recent output turn to black like it supposed too but the problem is all the previous output also turn to black. I want to make the previous output maintain the red color instead turn to black. which part of the code did I do wrong?

```
  If LblMsg.Text = "FAIL:Board Not Found. " Then

        TxtResult3.Text = Session("empID")
        TxtResult3.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red

    Else

        TxtResult3.Text = Session("empID")
        TxtResult3.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black


    End If
```

Answer:
I solve it with just by creating another session and a new textbox . so here's the code:

```
    If LblMsg.Text = "FAIL:Board Not Found. " Then

        TxtResult3.Text = Session("IntempID")
        TxtResult3.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red

    Else

        TxtResult4.Text = Session("empId")
        TxtResult4.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black


    End If
```

Comment: What type of control is `TxtResult3`? Are you saying that you want different parts of the text in it to be different colours?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, the TxtResult3 is a multiline. what I'm trying to do is if the 1st output meet the condition,it will turn the color to red and the color still maintained even though the 2nd output didn't meet then condition and the 2nd output stay black in color. The problem that I have is the previous output change the color according to the recent output on whether they meet the condition

Comment: A multiline text box can only have one colour for all the text in HTML. If I understand you correctly, perhaps something like an [`<asp:Literal>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal?view=netframework-4.7.2) would be better as you can then add things like `<div class="failureState">Uh-oh!</div><div class="normalState">F.A.B.</div>`.

Comment: okay thank you for the help. @AndrewMorton.